# Anecdotic vs. Anecdotal… sometimes synonyms, but fairly non-exchangeable?

Tags: synonyms, collocation

I’m a bit puzzled by these two words' meaning.
Observing examples and the use in context it looks like **anecdotal** is preferred to be used as an adjective with collocations such as: “anecdotal evidence”, “anecdotal accounts" and similar expressions.

**Anecdotic** seems to be more like an abstract quality term, more used when you refer to stories, scenes, facts and the way some people tell experiences. I’ve also noticed some collocations like to be “of the anecdotic kind”.

But maybe there’s more to it than I have grasped from what I’ve read. (?)
And sometimes they could be used interchangeably, but it’s not easy to figure out when for me (I’m a non-native speaker BTW).

Answer (score 3):

You seem to grasp the basic meanings. As a native speaker, I would just say that "anecdotic" is rather uncommon (I had to look it up) and you might consider avoiding it.

Comment: Please show basic research. You obviously found a definition / definitions of 'anecdotic'. Where? What are they? Merriam-Webster shows synonymity, but also boundaries for the overlap. Does any dictionary support your 'rather uncommon ... and you might consider avoiding it' observations? (I'd certainly agree ... CD doesn't list it, for instance, but answers lacking supporting references come across as – and may merely be – one person's opinion.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This falls under "you can't make everybody happy".  I originally posted this just as a comment because I didn't think it rose to the level of an answer.  But then I got chastised for that, so I posted it as an answer and, well,...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If it helps, you might consider [the OED’s frequency band](https://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/key-to-frequency/) assignments for these adjectives, each representing a different order of magnitude in frequency. They place ***anecdotal*** in band 5 with *preconceived* and *cumulative*, ***anecdotic*** in band 3 with *prelapsarian* and *contumacious*, ***anecdotical*** in band 2 with *geogenic* and *abactinal*, and ***anecdotive*** in band 1 with *abaptiston* and *abaxile*.

Comment: @tchrist Even I would post that as an answer (together with the M-W pronouncements).